# When will be ROS2 fully realtime compatible?

Tags: ros, ros2, linux, realtime, ardent

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am going to switch to ROS2 by realtime reasons. In some projects we need realtime ability because of security reasons.Going to use Linux with RT_PREEMPT kernel patch. So it would be interesting when all Realtime features will be available?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284902/when-will-be-ros2-fully-realtime-compatible?/) by [TBRob](https://answers.ros.org/users/34067/tbrob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OSRF has worked on a real-time demo in the past which is part of the ROS 2 release. The [tutorial page](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Real-Time-Programming) in the wiki is a good starting point for that referencing additional resources. Currently we are not actively working on that ares (see [roadmap](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Roadmap)) but focuc our efforts on various other topics.

From just reading your question it is unclear to me what you mean with "all Realtime features".  If real-time support is relevant for your use case I would suggest to look into what is already possible and start a discussion on what is not yet covered on e.g. discourse. We also encourage you to contribute whatever is necessary / helpful for your application to extend the support in that area.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-03-09**:
Also, while we've not bene actively investigating it lately, we are working with people who will be using parts of ROS 2 in realtime situations, but the important question is "which features and/or packages need to be realtime for your use case?" Not all of ROS 2 will be realtime safe.